# Iphone 5c will no longer play music without wifi or cellular

Tags: iphone

Always played music from my music library.  Today all I get is "connect to WiFi or cellular to play music".  I haven't done anything different or added anything!  Does anyone know why??

Comment: It looks like your iPhone is trying to play something from [iTunes Match](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146) (which is a paid service, BTW). Can you check (e.g. with an external tool like [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) if the music is really stored on your device, or only in iCloud.

Comment: @Glorfindel Feel free to pop that in as an answer either here or there. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207028/cant-play-any-music-off-line-from-iphone

Comment: Hi y Rose - if your situation isn't covered in the other post, just edit your question using the edit button to clearly show with some details why the other offline play issue is different than what you seek to do. It might be as simple as you need to connect momentarily to renew a certificate and check in with the cloud.